# Per File access Control on Drupal 7 Content

Tags: drupal-7

Is there a way to restrict content download "Restricting Anonymous Users From Downloading Files"

Right now, once the user is logged in and he is able to obtain the URL to a path, he can re-download it again even if he logs off.

We've tried 
-Rules Module and Content_Access Module to no avail.

it only supports:
Basic Rules per node

There's no
Basic Rules per Content (i.e. videos)

Answer (score 0):

You can control access to files via Drupal only if both conditions are met:

1. private mode is on (see /admin/config/media/file-system)
2. Download folder is outside web server access, i.e. file upload folder contents are not accessible from the web.

Answer (score 0):

See hook [hook_file_download()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_file_download/7) which is called for every private file.

> Control access to private file downloads and specify HTTP headers.
>
> This hook allows modules enforce permissions on file downloads when the private file download method is selected. Modules can also provide headers to specify information like the file's name or MIME type.